# Cannot get Cookie

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

Until now i always worked with session in Codeigniter. But now there is to much data for an session. I like to use cookies, but it doesn,t work for me.

- I first load the cookie helper in the autoload.
- I use this code to add data `$this->input->set_cookie('users_new',$users_new);`
- `var_dump($this->input->cookie('users_new'));` With this one i tried to get the data. But it is empty. The variabele `$users_new` is filled with an array, so it cannot be empty.

When i try this simple example, the cookie is alsoempty.

```
$cookie = array(
'name'   => 'some_value',
'value'  => 'The Value'
);
set_cookie($cookie);
var_dump(get_cookie('some_value'));
die();
```

Whats wrong?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are sent by the browser so you would have to wait the user reload a page.

So the basic process is:

1. you set a cookie
2. the user resend the cookie on the next request
3. you can access the cookie value using `get_cookie`

---

EDIT:

[`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.setcookie.php) is used this way, it won't work with an array

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire dans 1 heure */
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
```

so you should do:

```
foreach ($cookie as $key => $val) {
   setcookie($key, $val);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But after the redirect var_dump(get_cookie('some_value')); give a false. But in the controller i did this: $cookie = array(
'name'   => 'some_value',
'value'  => 'The Value'
);
set_cookie($cookie);

Answer (score 0):

1. You should set an expiration value, i.e. seconds from the moment it gets created to when it will expire.
2. the "name" value must be a string, not an array. If you want multiple infos, you can just [**serialize()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array.

Example code:

```
$cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'users_new',
    'value'  => serialize($users_new),
    'expire' => '86500'
);

$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

You don't need to load the cookie helper if you just use the input class. No problem, I know, just to avoid useless lines of code :)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies cannot hold arrays, just plain text. @RageZ had a good clue with the for loop which would set many cookies (as many as vars in array). @Damien suggests "serialized" and another option would be to jSon the array into a str with native php function "json_encode()"